# Are there any extensions for browsers that open a chatroom based on people searching for the same thing?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, plugins, safari

I was reading an old Linux Magazine and there was an article about a defunct project called ["search party"](https://live.gnome.org/SearchParty) which would [optionally open a chatroom](http://people.gnome.org/~seth/summerofcode/searchparty/sequence/index.html) when doing a google search so that you could talk to the other people who were searching for the same thing.

I'll admit the idea has maybe been kind of blown away by the advent of social media, but I still can't help but wonder if there is a plugin like this under another name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search through the Chrome extension store turned up [ToggleChat](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eihlaffnihacoobcpjklfeebpjponako).

Firefox Addons offers [SeekSpeak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/seekspeak/?src=search).

[Safari](http://extensions.apple.com/) doesn't list one, but also doesn't make searching for one very easy.

Internet Explorer [Add-on Gallery](http://www.iegallery.com/Addons) doesn't list one either.

Comment: @leeand00 or are those two not what you were actually talking about, and I got it wrong?

Comment: Yeah those are great, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks Bon!